# Why is my programming assuming an event binding is a string?

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

[Here is the entirety of my code (100 lines)](https://pastebin.com/LLchMWb6)

Specifically, this is the part giving an error:

```
def mouse_movement(self, angle, event= "<Motion>"):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    relx, rely = x - self.player_coord_x, self.player_coord_y
    self.angle = (180 / math.pi) * -math.atan2(rely, relx)
    p = Image.open("tank.png")
    p.rotate(angle)
    p2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(p)
    p2.image = p2
    player2 = c.create_image(self.coords[0], self.coords[1], image=p2)
```

In this part of the code, I am passing a parameter called `event`. It binds the mouse to the player's movement. However, it is giving me an Attribute Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\offcampus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\offcampus\Desktop\GameFolder\main.py", line 131, in <lambda>
    c.bind_all("<Motion>", lambda x2: player.mouse_movement(180))
  File "C:\Users\offcampus\Desktop\GameFolder\main.py", line 50, in mouse_movement
    x, y = event.x, event.y
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'x'
```

The program is taking the event parameter as a string, instead of taking it as a mouse binding. What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: Because the `event` you are passing is a string.

Comment: `event= "<Motion>"` sets it to a string by default.

Comment: @Barmar so should it be `event = <Motion>`?

Comment: No, it should be an Event object.

Comment: @10Rep that would be invalid syntax.

Comment: @RandomDavis I was aware of that, just wondering what to pass as the parameter.

Comment: When you call `bind`, tkinter passes in an event, by default(automatic), and I think it has to be the first parameter, and here you dont have it defined.

Comment: Just `event` should do it.

Comment: That's not how you "bind" a function to an event in tkinter. You do that via something like `my_widget.bind("<Motion>", my_function)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass the event in, therefore it's using the default event which you defined as the string `"<Motion>"`. To fix it, pass in the event object (which you have named `x2`):

```
c.bind_all("<Motion>", lambda x2: player.mouse_movement(180, x2))
```